# How to constrain varchar in mysql 5.1?

Tags: mysql

I need to create column in mysql 5.1 that can store user's feedback.
It shouldn't be too long, so I think not more 1000 characters of UTF-8.

The question is how to represent this efficiently in mysql 5.1.

For now I have:

```
`description` varchar NOT NULL,
```

But how to constrain `varchar` to hold at most 1000 characters of UTF-8?

Comment: Is that even valid? I think you need to specify a length with varchar.

Comment: But what length to set to tell varchar to hold at most 1000 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html):

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.

This means that you can store up to 65,535 bytes in a VARCHAR column. However, from the [String Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html):

> MySQL interprets length specifications in character column definitions in character units. (Before MySQL 4.1, column lengths were interpreted in bytes.) This applies to CHAR, VARCHAR, and the TEXT types.

So, declare  your table with a UTF8 collation and set the length of the varchar to 1,000 *characters* and MySQL will do the work for you behind the scenes.

Comment: So `varchar(1000)` means at most 1000 characters. Thanks!

Comment: I think by 'character unit' they mean 'code unit'. For UTF-8, a code unit is one byte, but a character can consist of multiple units. For UTF-16, a unit is 2 bytes, but a character can still be multiple units. I can't imagine MySQL solving this for you, since it needs to reserve space. A MySQL row is never more than 65536 bytes, so it cannot contain 65536 multi-byte/multi-unit UTF-8 characters. I'm not exactly sure of this (MySQL documentation isn't really clear on what they mean by 'character unit'), but it sounds to me as the only explanation.

Comment: Allright. Turns out we were both partially right. MySQL handles the characters. It is still limited to a records size of 65536 though, and therefor, a varchar field with a utf8 collation cannot be larger than 21844 characters (in its specification). This basically means that MySQL reserves 3 bytes per characters for UTF-8 fields, and it is just unable to store the [4 byte supplementary characters](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/supplementary-test.html#utf8) in a `varchar(1)` column. Suprising? Maybe not. Is is MySQL.

Comment: It would be better if you could define whether you wanted the column to be byte or char semantic @Golez, yes... I like your science.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Since the size is apparently defined in bytes, ... 
-correction- Field size is defined in 'character units'. It's a bit unclear what they mean by that, but I guess they mean '[code units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Code_unit)'.</strike>

Removed the rest of the detailed explanation, since it wasn't (entirely true).

Correction. In MySQL you actually define the number of characters in the field. It is still limited to the 65535 *byte* boundary though. Above that, MySQL just reserves 3 bytes per character for UTF-8, which means that you cannot have UTF-8 fields of more than 21844 characters, and declaring a field als VARCHAR(21900) will just fail for that reason: `" Column length too big for column 'field1' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead: "`. The number in this message is wrong, by the way. The actual maximum size is 21844. 21845 is 1/3 of 65535, but I guess you need to subtract the two bytes for the field size header as well.

The limit of 3 bytes is weird, though. The unicode definition is designed to be able to expand with extra characters. There are already supplementary characters of 4 bytes, that actually *cannot be stored* in a UTF-8 varchar(1) field, or any varchar field for that matter, since MySQL just doesn't seem able to read those characters: `"Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA0\x9C\x8E' for column 'field1' at row 1"`. So I guess you would need an actual binary/blob column to be able to store these characters.

I think the documentation about this subject is pretty poor, but I've tried some things and came to this conclusion. You can see the fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d938

To the question:

So for your specific situation, declaring the field as `varchar(1000)` will do the trick, presuming you don't want people to use the supplementary characters in their feedback.

Some things to consider though:

- I think a 'feedback' field of 1000 characters is pretty small. For many folks this will be enough, but if you have to say more, it is annoying if you can't. So I would make the field bigger.
- varchar fields are stored in the record and consume a part of the maximum row size of 65536 bytes. This is an important fact. You cannot have two varchar(20000) fields in a row, because together they would be larger than this maximum row size.
  A better alternative for large text fields would be therefor be to make them TEXT or MEDIUMTEXT, which can be even larger and are stored in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Comment: But how to translate 65,535 bytes to number of characters.